# Javascript date to C# date in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

I have a date like this `var jsDate = "2017-01-01";`

I want to put this `jsDate` like C# date: `(/Date(1425408717000)/)`

Also how can put this c# date `/Date(1425408717000)/` into JavaScript Json date?

Comment: momentJS can parse ASP.NET's weird date format: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/asp-net-json-date/ . I can't think of a reason you'd need to convert it back the other way on the JS side though, you should be able to just send an ISO date string to the server.

Comment: Please, please, please don't use `(/Date(1425408717000)/)` it's an abomination. `"2017-01-01"` is a standard format defined by [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and easily parseable (is that a word)

Comment: @phuzi if OP is getting data from some older ASP.NET ASMX or WCF webservices they may have no choice in the matter - the services spit out dates in this bizarre format when returning data. But as I mentioned earlier, momentJS can read them into a moment object (which can then be converted into a JS Date object, or a string) so it's not a massive issue, as long as using momentJS is not a problem for the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript you can try: `(new Date("2017-01-01")).getTime()` , which will give you  `1483228800000` if that's what you are looking for